# Does the order of a Java class matter?

Tags: java, layout, structure

Is there any difference between the following? :

Example 1:

```
public class OddEven {

private static void OddEven() {
    //some calculation.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   OddEven();
}
}
```

Example 2:

```
public class OddEven {

private static void main(String[] args) {
   OddEven();
}

private static void OddEven() {
    //some calculation.
}
}
```

The reason I ask is I would always go with example 2, putting Main first. Though most of the examples I've seen online put the methods first, before Main.

I've never had formal computing lessons, and I apologise if this is an obvious question, but I'd like to know:

- Is the order of the layout simply aesthetics, or convention?
- Does it make any difference in processing efficiency and/or memory?
- If so, is that saving seen for all programming languages?

Thanks for any help on this topic.

Comment: No difference in terms of memory

Comment: there is no difference with the main method, you can use it in anywhere within the class

Comment: I prefer to put static methods/state first because the flow of the code is more chronological, i.e. the classloader will initialize statics first. Then if creating an instance run the constructor, initializers, etc at the object level. Mixing static/object state makes the class more difficult to read and understand in my opinion.

If you look at the compiled byte code in a decompiler, or get the methods and state via reflection, you will find that regardless of the order in the source code the byte code is all jumbled up and in a different, arbitrary, order.

Comment: order matters in C++ for certain (class members are initialised in the order they are in the class definition) - I think this is the same in Java

Comment: @JohnGaughan Is that preference shared by most Java developers then?

Comment: @Jimmy the order does matter in certain cases. For example, specifying a `static final` constant then using it in another `static` variable: the constant has to come first (true of variable declarations or `static` blocks). But this is true of both Java and C++. You cannot use something until you declare it.

Comment: @user2514440 I do not think so. In my experience, most developers are sloppy and mix up static/object state/methods like frogs in a blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order does not matter. But there is a common courtesy to public methods and static methods at the beginning of a class. This is just a developers choice

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no difference. Java doesn't care about the declaration order of methods in a class.

Comment: That is a bit of a shortcut. The order does matter in some circumstances (but not in this specific example).

Comment: @assylias: Do you mean if one member declaration references another? That is the only case I can think of.

Comment: Yes - the methods order doesn't matter but the members order in general does.

Comment: @assylias: Yeah, went a bit too general there I suppose. Normally member declaration order doesn't matter either, but it is definitely not true for all cases.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not matter in which order you declare functions.It can be handier for youself to do it in a certain order, but not for the machine

Answer (score 2):

**No** java program start execution from main method and order of function call is important not the oder in which they are define